# How to get selenium server running locally?

Tags: selenium, selenium-server

I need to have selenium server running in order to run some tests I'm creating in http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/

This is not for the selniumIDE and not for a server grid, I need to be able to export from selenium builder and am directed to run them on a local selenium server, e.g. localhost:4444

[image]

I use the download page at http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ but there isn't much info on basic stuff.

I see the link for the download and I can save the .jar file  Now what?  I don't know Java. Trying to click thru gets

[[image]
[[image]

How should I be compiling and then using it?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium means different things depending on context.

---

Do you want to record/playback simple web browser interactions?  You want SeleniumIDE or [Selenium Builder](https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/se-builder/wiki/Getting-Started). You need a standalone jar when replaying the tests from the command line; I think the docs tell you how but I couldn't find it. [This small blog post](https://zscribble.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/how-to-run-selenium-ide-tests-from-command-line/) tells you how. Essentially: download the Selenium Standalone Server jar file from [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and run it something like this:

```
java -jar c:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://localhost:8080" "c:\test\my-test-suite.html" "c:\test\my-test-result.html"
```

(Note: even though it is called a "server", in this mode it does not listen on a port for incoming requests or anything like that; to most people's way of thinking, the jar file is actually a client in this mode, and the browser that it connects to is the server! The jar file does include a server, you're just not using it when executing a Selenese file like this.)

---

Do you want to run tests locally from your unit test runner (JUnit, NUnit, etc.?). You probably don't need a server. All the instructions are [on this doc page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-and-the-selenium-server).

---

Do you want to run the tests via a grid of multiple browsers, allowing you to distribute the load and do multi-browser testing easily? This is where Selenium server shines. Everything you need to know is [on this doc page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#quick-start).

Comment: Not IDE and not grid, I need to be able to export from selenium builder and am directed to run them on a local selenium server

Comment: I've never used it (never even heard of it!) but it looks like an updated SeleniumIDE to me. It records to Selenese unless you ask to export to another language. If you're exporting to Selenese, then you want the SeleniumIDE docs and the blog post I linked to. You don't need to compile anything, you just need a single jar file and a well-constructed command line.

Comment: The Selenium Builder docs even say you use Selenium RC (pre-webdriver) to run the scripts, though the link they provide goes nowhere. Use the information in the l[inked blog post](https://zscribble.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/how-to-run-selenium-ide-tests-from-command-line/) to run your Selenese scripts.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  It helps that it shows the command to run the server.  Still not sure of the compile steps.  The linked page says "You will need Selenium server to run the tests from command line.".  I've run into these sort of hurdles before using seleniumhg.org's documentation and have found it hard to use.  I'd do anything for a Stack Overflow answer that has the concrete steps for the install and use that can be a definitive answer for others in the same situation.  Links are helpful but direct steps would improve the answer.  Plus one for your help.

Comment: There are no compile steps. The jar file is already compiled and assembled for you. You just need to download the file and use it as a command-line application. I've updated the answer for clarity, hopefully that gets you closer to where you need to be?